# Query RDS postgres log size

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I don't have console access, only query access to a postgres 12.5 aws rds db.

```
show log_destination ;--stderr
show logging_collector ; --on
show log_directory ; --/rdsdbdata/log/error
show log_filename ; --postgresql.log.%Y-%m-%d-%H
```

Is there a sql command I can run to determine the total size of all the logs in my rds instance?